Does Xcode automatically delete old iOS versions?
When I opened Xcode today, it asked me to download the latest iOS version, which I accepted. Is the previous iOS version still on my disk, though? Is it auto-deleted, and if not where can I go to manually delete it? I'm not seeing anything in Xcode's settings.

Yes, previous version is still on your disk. You can delete them manually by going to Xcode menu -> Settings -> Platforms. There you can find all installed OS versions and delete those that not needed by right clicking on it.
Also if you need to free additional space you can go to Window menu -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators and remove installed simulators that you don't need at the moment.
